# Semigroup theory for non-symmetric Markov processes / complex-valued potentials

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators, semigroups-of-operators

Let $X$ be a continuous-time Markov process on a countable state space $E$, and let $V:E\mapsto\mathbb C$ be some complex function. $X$ can be characterized by its transition rates
$(\lambda_{xy})_{x,y\in E,~x\neq y}$, i.e.,
$$\mathbb P[X_{t+\epsilon}=y|X_{t}=x]=\lambda_{xy}\epsilon+o(\epsilon)$$
as $\epsilon\to0$.

If we define the semigroup
$$T_tf(x)=\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(-\int_0^tV(X_s)~ds\right)f(X_t)\bigg|X_0=x\right]
\tag{1}$$
then back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest that
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\langle1_x,(1-T_t)1_y\rangle}{t}=\begin{cases}
-\lambda_{xy}&\text{if }x\neq y,\\
(\sum_{z\neq x}\lambda_{xz})V(x)&\text{if }x=y.
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

In the case where $X$ is symmetric and $V$ is real-valued, I can easily find a multitude of references proving that, under general conditions on $X$ and $V$ (e.g., Kato class, etc), the semigroup $(1)$ is strongly continuous on $L^2(E,\mathbb R)$, and that its generator $(2)$ is a densely defined self-adjoint operator (see, e.g., [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764358877), which actually treats much more general state spates).

> **Question.** Are there similar references for the non-self-adjoint case? I.e., general conditions on $X$ (which allow for the process to be non-symmetric) and $V$ (which allow for $V$ to be complex-valued) under which $(1)$ is strongly continuous on $L^2(E,\mathbb C)$, and the generator ($2$) is closed and densely defined?

Given that I'm only interested in the case of a countable state space, I expect that this should not be too hard to do from scratch, but I suspect that this must have been done before.